# Importing multiple Esri ASC files into GRASS, then exporting to Unreal Engine

Tags: grass-gis, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to import LiDAR scan data from Defra in the UK into Grass.  The data appears to be in Esri ASC format, in multiple separate files.

[image: folder structure and file content of asc files]

As this is the first time I've used GRASS I'm struggling a bit!  I've managed to get one tile in using the Grass GUI and Import raster data - Import of common raster formats r.in.gdal.  The issue is I can't work out how to import multiple tiles into the same map.

The reason I'm trying to do this is to then create something I can import into Unreal Engine 4.

Comment: If it helps the dataset was downloaded from here - https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?Mode=survey

To be more accurate I'm trying to import all .asc files in 2 folders (each folder contains one map square in multiple tiles) into the same map.

Comment: The fastest way will be to first create a VRT mosaic, using `gdalbuildvrt`, then import the VRT file into GRASS GIS using r.import.

Comment: BTW: this are not LiDAR point clouds (can be import in case with https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.in.pdal.html) but already gridded elevation data.